# What is the easier way to initialize a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working in a 2D matrix with a simple polynomial algorithm:

```
for i in range(len(content1)):
    for j in range(len(content2)):
        if content1[i]==content2[j]:
            matrix[i][j]=1
        else:
            matrix[i][j]=0
```

This code itself do not compile for a simple reason. dot_matrix is not initialized. So what is the easier way to do that?

Also, how could I implement the same logic I'm using above in a one lined code like this:

> matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(content1))] for x in range(len(content2))]

Comment: If you're looking for performance - don't use python, and if you're using python - stop looking for negligible performance optimizations

Comment: Why are you not using NumPy for matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you're using content1 as the outer index in the first chunck of code, so matric should be initialized with content1 on the outer as well:

```
matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(content2))] for x in range(len(content1))]
```

And yes, you can do it in one line like the other answer mentions:

```
matrix = [[1 if i == j else 0 for j in content2] for i in content1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `x`s with `i` and `j`, then replace the `0` with `(1 if content1[i]==content2[j] else 0)`.